# How to make HATEOAS render empty embedded array

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

Usually `CollectionModel` will return an `_embedded` array, but in this example:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/productMaterials")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getProductMaterials(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Optional<Material> optionalMaterial = materialRepository.findById(id);
        if (optionalMaterial.isPresent()) {
            List<ProductMaterial> productMaterials = optionalMaterial.get().getProductMaterials();
            CollectionModel<ProductMaterialModel> productMaterialModels =
                    new ProductMaterialModelAssembler(ProductMaterialController.class, ProductMaterialModel.class).
                            toCollectionModel(productMaterials);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(productMaterialModels);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("no such material");
    }
```

if the `productMaterials` is empty `CollectionModel` will not render the `_embedded` array which will break the client. Is there any ways to fix this?

Comment: you will have to use an EmbeddedWrapper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286795/how-to-force-spring-hateoas-resources-to-render-an-empty-embedded-array
you should mark you resource explicitly to render an empty _embedded array

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you show me how to write it? I have no idea what the author was talking about :((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (optionalMaterial.isPresent()) {
        List<ProductMaterial> productMaterials = optionalMaterial.get().getProductMaterials();
        CollectionModel<ProductMaterialModel> productMaterialModels =
                new ProductMaterialModelAssembler(ProductMaterialController.class, ProductMaterialModel.class).
                        toCollectionModel(productMaterials);
        if(productMaterialModels.isEmpty()) {
            EmbeddedWrappers wrappers = new EmbeddedWrappers(false);
            EmbeddedWrapper wrapper = wrappers.emptyCollectionOf(ProductMaterialModel.class);
            Resources<Object> resources = new Resources<>(Arrays.asList(wrapper));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new Resources<>(resources));
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(productMaterialModels);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  it worked :)) since the ```Resources``` does not exist anymore, i change the code a little bit

Comment: Is spring HATEOAS popular right now? All the solutions seem to be deprecated and _not elegant_ at all.

Comment: @LaHai how did you change the code? I can't find the `Resources` class.

Comment: @Raman Happy new year. I believe it's `CollectionModel` now. You can find the changes in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#migrate-to-1.0.changes)

Answer (score 0):

It could be easily done now using this code:

```
    List<ProductMaterial> productMaterials = optionalMaterial.get().getProductMaterials();
    return HalModelBuilder.emptyHalModel()
            .embed(productMaterials, ProductMaterial.class)
            .build();
```